# How to compute gradient from intermediate layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Trying to adapt an internet code to another mode/code I have (Tensorflow 1.15.0)

2 main differences:

1. in the internet code, the "model" is like an imported module; in my code the graph/model is described in the main function as layers collection and called from a .ckpt file (and later saver.restore)
2. my code/model has not attributes calling layers (as .y_logits, .resized_image, .y_pred, that exists in the internet model)

The part of the internet code I'm adapting is:

```
model = inception.Inception()
resized_image = model.resized_image
y_logits = model.y_logits
with model.graph.as_default():
    pl_cls_target = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)
    loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_logits, labels=[pl_cls_target])
    gradient = tf.gradients(loss, resized_image)
```

**I've success** with this: (where "lastLayer" is the **very last layer** of my model with 100 output values)

```
resized_image = lastLayer.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Placeholder_1:0')
logits = lastLayer
with lastLayer.graph.as_default():
    pl_cls_target = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(logits, pl_cls_target))
    gradient = tf.gradients(loss, resized_image)
```

Now, I'd like to compute the gradient from another **intermediate layer** that has 2048 values.

Watching into the graph with:

```
op = session.graph.get_operations()
[m.values() for m in op]
```

all the "lines" with 2048 are:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'random_uniform_14/RandomUniform:0' shape=(100, 2048) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'random_uniform_14/mul:0' shape=(100, 2048) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'random_uniform_14:0' shape=(100, 2048) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'layer_3/fully_connected/weights:0' shape=(100, 2048) dtype=float32_ref>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'layer_3/fully_connected/weights/Assign:0' shape=(100, 2048) dtype=float32_ref>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'layer_3/fully_connected/weights/read:0' shape=(100, 2048) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'Const_14:0' shape=(2048,) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'layer_3/fully_connected/biases:0' shape=(2048,) dtype=float32_ref>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'layer_3/fully_connected/biases/Assign:0' shape=(2048,) dtype=float32_ref>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'layer_3/fully_connected/biases/read:0' shape=(2048,) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'l2_normalize/Square:0' shape=(100, 2048) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor      shape=(1, 2048) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'l2_normalize/Maximum:0' shape=(1, 2048) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'l2_normalize/Rsqrt:0' shape=(1, 2048) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'l2_normalize:0' shape=(100, 2048) dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'save/Assign_25:0' shape=(2048,) dtype=float32_ref>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'save/Assign_26:0' shape=(100, 2048) dtype=float32_ref>,)
```

I've tried changing just my "logits" variable calling some of these layers.
For example:

```
resized_image = lastLayer.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Placeholder_1:0')
logits = lastLayer.graph.get_tensor_by_name('l2_normalize/Rsqrt:0')
with lastLayer.graph.as_default():
    pl_cls_target = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(logits, pl_cls_target))
    gradient = tf.gradients(loss, resized_image)
```

but **without success** (gradient is always None).

Any idea?